# What is the difference between mongodb and tuple space storages

Tags: mongodb

There are some **storage space** type like `GigaSpaces`. that inspired from **tuple space**.
Would you say `mongodb` can act like a **tuple space** or not?
What is the difference between `mongo` and `tuple space`?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is document-oriented NOSQL database.

A tuple space is an implementation of the associative memory paradigm for parallel/distributed computing and may be thought as a form of distributed shared memory.

Databases primary jobs are the storage and retrieval of information on disk. Memory is data that is for immediate use and is often not persisted (like disk storage).

Thus, the foundation ideas are very different between the two technologies.